# Native Ads overlapped RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, native-ads

I try to implement Native Ads inside RecyclerView. The ad should be placed every 3 items in recycler view. I use a native ads template. Ads are loaded but they have overlapped items in RecyclerView. I try couple of solution but they didn't work. Please help me, thank you in advance.

Below is the code for Adapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

Context c;
ArrayList<Model> models;

private static final int CONTENT_TYPE = 1;
private static final int AD_TYPE = 0;


public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Model> models) {
    this.c = c;
    this.models = models;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position % 3 == 0) {
        return AD_TYPE;
    } else {
        return CONTENT_TYPE;
    }

}

class adViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TemplateView adTemplate;

    public adViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        adTemplate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == AD_TYPE) {
        adViewHolder myadViewHolder = new adViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_ads, null, false));
        return myadViewHolder;
    } else {
        MyHolder myHolder = new MyHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, null, false));
        return myHolder;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (getItemViewType(position) == CONTENT_TYPE) {

        ((MyHolder) holder).mTitle.setText(models.get(position).getTitle());
        ((MyHolder) holder).mDescription.setText(models.get(position).getDesc());
        ((MyHolder) holder).mImageView.setImageResource(models.get(position).getImage());
    } else if (getItemViewType(position) == AD_TYPE) {
        final AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(c, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110")
                .forUnifiedNativeAd(new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
                        NativeTemplateStyle styles = new NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().build();
                        TemplateView template = ((adViewHolder) holder).adTemplate;
                        template.setStyles(styles);
                        template.setNativeAd(unifiedNativeAd);
                    }
                })
                .withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {

                    }
                })
                .withNativeAdOptions(new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                        .build())
                .build();
        adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return models.size();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting ADs in fixed-size view holders? Since your ads are not loaded immediately, RecyclerView may not be readjusting row heights after the ad is loaded. Another problem you have is that you need to return models.size() + the number of ADs you plan to show in your getItemCount().

Comment: no I haven't try fixed-size view holders. How can I return ads in getItemCount()? I want to show 3 ads because I have got 10 items in recyclerview (3 ads every 3 items)

Comment: You can try setting a fixed height  in dp to your item_ads.xml, and if you are going to show 3 ads only you can do: return models.size() + 3; in your getItemCount(). This function tells the recyclerview how many items there are to display, and since you are inserting 3 ads in your recycler, you have to add these in your calculation as well.

Comment: when I set in getItemType "position == 3" that ad should be placed in 3 place and in return models.size() + 1 apps crush. Can u show me some snippet of code maybe it will be easier?